# What statistical model should be used to analyze data from a randomized pretest-posttest controlled trial when subgroups exist?

Tags: repeated-measures, ancova, clinical-trials, random-allocation

I'm planning a randomized pretest-posttest controlled trial of a psychological therapy intervention group compared to an active control group on a dependent variable of interest. My population will include employees at two firms who are randomly allocated to the treatment or control group. However, employees at these firms are also members of subgroups within each respective firm - e.g., Team 1, 2, 3, and so on. Employees within these subgroups may be more similar to those between subgroups. While I would typically apply a one-factor between-groups ANCOVA model to data generated from these designs (baseline as covariate), I think this would ignore the subgroup information. What model would be appropriate to apply to these data to answer the question of whether there is a difference in means at posttest between these two groups?

Comment: Are you interested in adjusting for the effect of group on treatment?

Comment: After some thought I think the concern here is contamination - if randomly allocated to the intervention as a cohort within a firm there may be receipt of the active intervention among participants in the control group due to close contact within teams. My understanding is that this is an issue of design rather than statistics.

Comment: You are wise to recognize the potential for contamination before embarking on the study. The power of a randomized trial is in the design, not the analysis.